# viewDidAppear tab switch vs nav pop

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Is there a way for me to differentiate between wether the my view controller viewDidAppear method got called after a user switched a tab or after the navigation controller was popped?

Thanks

Comment: Clarify what you mean for navigation controller was popped. Do you mean the view is not pushed into navigation stack, but presented as a modal?

Answer (score 1):

viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear both get called on navigation pop and tabbar switch, you could differentiate it by using the tab bar delegate method (implement it if you have not done it yet)

```
- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item
```

may be set a Bool here or something.

```
- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item
{
     YOUR_VIEW_STATUS = YES;
}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self viewDidAppear:YES];

    if(!YOUR_VIEW_STATUS)
    {  
    //navigation pop or push
    }

    else
    {
    //tab bar switch
    }
}
```